# PHP else statement not executing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My else statement is not getting executed when it should. There are no errors in the code. It simply has to do with the flow of my query and foreach statement but I cannot seem to figure this out. Any ideas?

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$session_id = $this->input->post('session_id');
$q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * 
     FROM default_cart 
     WHERE cookie_id = '$session_id' 
     AND product_id = '$id' LIMIT 1");

foreach($q1->result() as $row) {
    if($row->cookie_id != $session_id && $row->product_id != $id) {
        echo json_encode(array('error_code' => 'e100'));
    } else {
        $data = array('product_id' => $id,
            'active' => 'Yes',
            'cookie_id' => $session_id
        );
        $this->db->insert('default_cart', $data);
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to test/output the variables you are querying with and the results you are getting from your query to find out why you don't match the conditions you have set.

Comment: Your loop is strange. You are explicitly querying only the datasets that are matching `cookie_id = $session_id` and `product_id = $id`, but you expect the database to return something else, so you saw the need to check again with an if. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would like to suggest that **there is no sense of looping through the query when there is only one record `LIMIT 1` and no sense of if check while you have already checked the all parameters in the query `WHERE cookie_id = '$session_id' AND product_id = '$id'`** just fetch the row returned by the query and check for empty or not.

```
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $session_id = $this->input->post('session_id');
    $q1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_cart
    WHERE cookie_id = '$session_id' AND product_id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
    $row=$q1->row();
    if(!empty($row)) {           
            $data = array('product_id' => $id,
                          'active' => 'Yes',
                          'cookie_id' => $session_id);
            $this->db->insert('default_cart', $data);
            echo json_encode(array('success' => true));

    }else{
    echo json_encode(array('error_code' => 'e100'));
    }
```